# customtkinter.__init__ warning in vscode

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, customtkinter

I am newbie. I am trying to make a gui project. When I run my code in Spyder it is running perfectly. When I run in the vscode, it produce an error message. Like this:
[image: error message]

I used the customtkinter while building gui. I did not find any solution on internet. Please help me.

Comment: Have you tried to contact the developer about this?

Comment: No did not. Should I contact him?

Comment: I would recommend it. I find it unlikely that someone fixes this with lesser effort than the developer.

Answer (score 0):

Try to update to the newest version of customtkinter 4.6.1. I recently changed the Linux font directory from `~/.fonts/` to `~/.local/share/fonts/` but somehow this doesn't seem to work on all platforms. So now I reverted back to the old font install location which should work. Which version of Ubuntu are you using?